# New Ender 3 Pro Thermal Runaway

Tags: creality-ender-3, thermal-runaway

I just assembled my Ender 3 last night, this is my first printer and I’m new to this all. After about 10-15 minutes into printing it consistently gives me a thermal runaway error. Any help would be appreciated.

The (part cooling) fan is spinning.

Comment: Photo of the machine please?

Answer (score 0):

Thermal runaway occurs when the hotend is on, but the sensor does not pickup any temperature increase. In many cases the thermistor is broken or the connection is bad.
A friend of mine had the thermistor broken on his Ender 3 pro. It worked sometimes and sometimes not. Buy a new thermistor.(a few $ only) and replace it to be sure.